# C# async - creating a task properly

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm creating a Task in C# but I'm not sure what I do is correct. I'm using Restsharp and in Restsharp there are two methods: Execute and ExecuteAsync. I want to do an Async call but I also need to return data to the client without blocking the execution.

Therefore I created a task which will use Execute instead of ExecuteAsync. The reason why is because I have to wait until I get a response back and then return it in the right data structure. So I thought there is no use in using ExecuteAsync if I have to await it in a Task...

My code looks as follows:

```
        public Task<Response> ExecuteAsync()
        {
        return new Task<Response>(() =>
        {
            var client = new RestClient(URL);

            if (_useBasicAuth)
            {
                client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_username, _password);
            }

            var request = RequestBuilder(_method);
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            return new Response()
            {
                HttpStatusCode = response.StatusCode,
                HttpStatusDescription = response.StatusDescription,
                Content = response.Content,
                Cookies = ExtractCookies(response.Cookies),
                Headers = ExtractHeaders(response.Headers)
            };
        });
    }
```

Is this correct? The client should be able to call ExecuteAsync without blocking the execution.

Comment: Use `.ExecuteAsync`. If you didn't have the `return new Task<Response>(() => {  ... });` stuff wrapping your method, your code would execute on the calling thread (block execution) until `await client.ExecuteAsync(request);` and then the rest of the code would resume on (probably) a different thread when you `await` your `ExecuteAsync` method. Given how light everything up to the `client.ExecuteAsync` point is, I don't see how this would cause you and significant delays.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I also need to return data to the client without blocking the execution"? It's really not clear why you think your requirements mean you need to use `Execute` - or why you're not just writing an async method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect you should really just use `ExecuteAsync` and write an `async` method:

```cs
public async Task<Response> ExecuteAsync()
{
    var client = new RestClient(URL);
    if (_useBasicAuth)
    {
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_username, _password);
    }

    var request = RequestBuilder(_method);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return new Response
    {
        HttpStatusCode = response.StatusCode,
        HttpStatusDescription = response.StatusDescription,
        Content = response.Content,
        Cookies = ExtractCookies(response.Cookies),
        Headers = ExtractHeaders(response.Headers)
    };
}
```

Comment: But would that not block the execution? If I call ExecuteAsync somewhere will it not block the execution were await stands? Or does it await on a seperate thread so that the main thread will still continue?

Comment: @John: No, it won't. It will return an incomplete task, which will complete when the rest of the async method completes. The whole *point* of asynchrony is to avoid blocking. I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ carefully.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll have a read though!